# what would be the value set in the calender instance c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -365 * 4)?

Tags: java, calendar

here is the code..

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -365 * 4);
Date date = c.getTime();
```

Can anyone tell me, what exactly we are setting in "c" ? what the use of -365 * 4

Comment: Why don't you print it and see for yourself?

Comment: try printing `c.getTime()` after the operation..

Comment: It was printing a whole lot of junk , i just wanted to know the use of -365 * 4 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code says that the Year will be set to fours years back from now. so it should be year 2010

Comment: No it doesn't, it says it should remove 4 times 365 days which is almost four years. It is just a non-working way of saying c.add(Calendar.YEAR, -4);

Comment: `c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -365 * 4);` - this set the year to 2010. But doing this way has an issue with no concern for leap years. Your snippet will address that concern. My post here is an answer the OP

Comment: Thanks for the ans. Actually i was debugging the old code and while printing it display a very long object. this was basically set as a date for a query string to fetch 4 years data (which i got to know now )